# How to prove an inequality with positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a_{1},...,a_{n} >0$, such that $a_{1} + \ldots +a_{n} =1$. Show that

$$
\left(\frac{1}{a_{1}^{2}} + \ldots +\frac{1}{a_{n}^{2}} \right)\left(2(a_{1}^{2}+\ldots+a_{n}^{2}) - \frac{1}{n}\right)\ge n^2.
$$

I tried induction, but it does not work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=(1,...,1), y=(a_1,...,a_n), z=(\frac{1}{a_1},..., \frac{1}{a_n}) \in \mathbb R^n$

1. By Cauchy Schwarz:

   $1=a_1+...+a_n=<x,y> \le ||x||*||y||$, hence

   $$1 \le n(a_1^2+...+a_n^2).$$
2. Again by Cauchy - Schwarz

$n=<y,z> \le ||y||*||z||$, thus

$$n^2 \le (\frac{1}{a_{1}^{2}} + \ldots +\frac{1}{a_{n}^{2}})(a_{1}^{2}+\ldots+a_{n}^{2}).$$

From 1. we see:

$a_{1}^{2}+\ldots+a_{n}^{2} \le 2(a_{1}^{2}+\ldots+a_{n}^{2})-\frac{1}{n}$

and we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we obtain
$$
a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2\ge \frac{1}{n}(a_1+\cdots+a_n)=\frac{1}{n},
$$
and hence
$$
2(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)-\frac{1}{n}\ge a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2.
$$
Next, Cauchy-Schwarz again
$$
(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)\left(\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right)\ge (1+\cdots+1)^2=n^2,
$$
and hence
$$
\big(2(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)-\frac{1}{n}\big)\left(\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right)
\ge (a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)\left(\frac{1}{a_1^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n^2}\right)\
\ge n^2.
$$